Comparison principle for a type of PDE with Neumann condition on a unbounded domain
We define a domain
$$\Gamma = \{(x_1, x_2, y) \in \mathbf R^3: x_1 < y\}.$$
Consider a PDE with $(x_1, x_2, y) := (x, y)$
$$\frac{1}{2} \Delta_x v(x, y) + b(x) \cdot D_x v(x, y) - v(x, y) + L(x) = 0, \ (x, y) \in \Gamma,$$
with boundary condition
$$
D_y^+ v(x, y) = - 1, \ (x, y) \in \partial \Gamma.
$$
In the above, $b$ and $L$ are all given functions with Lipschitz continuity.
(Question) I wonder if there is an established comparison principle for the viscosity sub and super solutions of this PDE. For instance,

(Guess) Let $u$ and $v$ be uniformly bounded sub and super solutions in viscosity sense. Then $u\le v$ on $\bar \Gamma$.

Remark: In the above, $\Delta_x v = \sum_{i=1}^2 \partial_{x_i}^2 v$ and $D_y^+ v = \lim_{y' \downarrow y} \frac{v(x, y') - v(x, y)}{y' - y}$.
Two points are worth mentioning:
First, the boundary condition is not the standard Neumann boundary condition
since it's not given in the form of $f(n(x)) = 0$ for the outward normal $n(x)$.
Another thing is that the domain is a half space, which is unbounded.
Therefore, our desired comparison principle should hold for polynomial growth function space.
I'd like to know if there is any reference for this type of PDE? Thanks.

Kenneth, firs of all, is $x\triangleq (x_1, x_2)$? Second, and more important: unless you require a well defined behaviour at infinity, this is a Cauchy problem on a the open semispace defined by $\Gamma$ and I possibly see two problems: 1) it seems underdetermined, and 2) it could be not well posed in any usual function space.

@DanieleTampieri Thanks. Yes, it is $x= (x_1, x_2)$. $\Gamma$ can be considered as a parabolic domain if we consider $x_2$ as time, but the derivative in $x_2$ is second order. Moreover, I do not see either initial/terminal value of $v$ in $x_2$ to be considered as a Cauchy problem.

The problem is not uniformly elliptic (no $y$ derivatives at all). What is the type of comparison principle you want to show then? That could help clarifying the issue in Daniele's comment.

@BertoldoBaccalà I've added my expected guess to the original post, which may be not correct. By the way, why the uniform ellipticity in $y$ is crucial to the comparison?

You're right, the low-order term $-v(x,y)$, could suffice in principle.
